# Calling twitter stream API using nodejs. No tweets are returned

Tags: node.js, twitter

Here is the code that I have written for calling twitter stream APi but no tweets are returned.

I am using the keys provided by twitter, here I have given just the names to hide it.

```
var twit = require('twitter');
twitter = new twit({
    consumer_key:'consumer_key',
    consumer_secret:'consumer_secret',
    access_token_key:'access_token_key',
    access_token_secret:'access_token_secret'
});
 twitter.stream(
            'statuses/filter',
            {track: ['amor', 'odio', 'love', 'hate']},
            function (stream) {
                stream.on('data', function (data,err) {
                    if(err){
                        console.log('no tweets');
                    }
                    if(data){
                       stream.destroy();
                       process.exit(0);
                       console.log(data);
                    }
                    //console.log(data.user.screen_name + " : " + data.text);
                    //io.sockets.emit('newTwitt', data);
                    // throw  new Exception('end');
                });

            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment out `process.exit(0);` before `console.log(data)` and it should work (I tested and it did for me).

That is causing your script to exit before `data` is shown on the console.